# MySQL return table name with field data for all tables in a DB

Tags: mysql, database, field

I was wondering if it were possible to write a query that would return:

Table | Field | Type | Null | Key

For all of the tables in a DB (Table = table name).  I could probably figure a way of building an HTML table with php, but I figured I'd ask if there was a way to achieve this with just one query.  I'm looking for a similar output to the following:

Users | UserName | varchar(30) | NOT NULL | PRIMARY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html) views and tables.  These can provide the information you're looking for.  Specifically, `information_schema.tables` and `information_schema.columns`.

Comment: I don't have access to the information_schema, I only have select privileges.

Comment: Actually i only have access to the one DB on the server - so I can't even see the other DBs.

Comment: As far as I know, then, this won't be possible.  `information_schema` is the generally accepted way to do what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

As unprivileged user, I can get this

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
describe account
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Field             |Type                            |Null|Key|Default|Extra         |
|account_id        |int(10) unsigned                |NO  |PRI|<NULL> |auto_increment|
|product_cd        |varchar(10)                     |NO  |MUL|<NULL> |              |
```

from executing "describe " like any other SELECT.